# How to add name attribute of input field dynamically using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need one help.I need to add input field name attribute dynamically using Javascript/Jquery. I am each time creating new field by clicking on `+` button and delete the required field by clicking on `-` button.I am explaining my code below.

```js
function createNew(evt){
  $('#questionshowp1').append('<div class="form-group"><input name="questions1" id="questions1" class="form-control firstsec" placeholder="Text, Image URL, or LaTeX" value="" type="text"><div class="secondsec"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success exp-add" style="line-height:12px;" onclick="createNew(this);"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger exp-minus" style="line-height:12px;" onclick="deleteNew(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div></div>');
  $(evt).css('display', 'none');
  $(evt).siblings("button.btn-danger").css('display', 'block');
}
function deleteNew(evnt){
  $(evnt).closest(".form-group").remove();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="questionshowp" id="questionshowp1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input name="questions0" id="questions0" class="form-control firstsec" placeholder="Text, Image URL, or LaTeX" value="" type="text">
    <div class="secondsec">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success exp-add" style="line-height:12px;" onclick="createNew(this);"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger exp-minus" style="line-height:12px;display:none;" onclick="deleteNew(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>                                                            
  </div>
</div>
```

Here i am creating new field using `+` button and here i need to increment the name attribute value like `questions0,questions1,questions2....` this.Suppose user delete any field then also this given order will remain with all field as name attribute value.Please help me.

Comment: Make global variable in js. Something like `questionnumber=1;` and then append it to strings `'...question' + questionnumber + '"  id=...'`

Comment: Let me understand.. If user add 2 questions, the result will `question0, question`. Then he delete the second and add one more. Is the result suppose to be `question0, question2`?

Comment: suppose user added `3` question `question0,question1,question2..` and deleted the middle one(`i.e-question1`) then it will again `question0,question1` after deletion.

Comment: If the name doesnt really matter and you just need to pass them all, you could use `name="questions[]"`.  But this would not work for id.

Comment: why i am doing this because when i will submit form i can extract those easily in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look attached snippet.

```js
function createNew(evt){
  var cur=$("input:text").length+1;
  
     $('#questionshowp1').append('<div class="form-group"><input name="questions'+cur+'" id="questions1" class="form-control firstsec" placeholder="Text, Image URL, or LaTeX" value="" type="text"><div class="secondsec"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success exp-add" style="line-height:12px;" onclick="createNew(this);">+<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger exp-minus" style="line-height:12px;" onclick="deleteNew(this)">-<i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div></div>');
     $(evt).css('display', 'none');
     $(evt).siblings("button.btn-danger").css('display', 'block');
  var i=0;
   $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
      $(this).attr('name', 'questions' + i); 
      $(this).attr('id', 'questions' + i); 
     i++;
  });
}
function deleteNew(evnt){
     $(evnt).closest(".form-group").remove();
   var i=0;
   $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
      $(this).attr('name', 'questions' + i); 
      $(this).attr('id', 'questions' + i); 
     i++;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questionshowp" id="questionshowp1">
<div class="form-group">
<input name="questions0" id="questions0" class="form-control firstsec" placeholder="Text, Image URL, or LaTeX" value="" type="text">
<div class="secondsec">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success exp-add" style="line-height:12px;" onclick="createNew(this);">+<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger exp-minus" style="line-height:12px;display:none;" onclick="deleteNew(this)">-<i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>                                                            
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This would cause more than one to have the same name when you delete one, wouldnt it?

Comment: @ Divyesh : Its fine but i need to reset the name attribute value after deletion.Please read my comment above.

Comment: Let me change as per requirement...:)

Comment: Ok @DivyeshPatoriya.

Comment: @ Divyesh Patoriya : No,Its not working as per requirement.Let me to explain again.`
 
suppose user added 3 question question0,question1,question2.. and deleted the middle one(i.e-question1) then it will again question0,question1 after deletion`.

Comment: Have you checked ?

Comment: Its always maintain sequence. question0,question1,question2,question3  and if we delete question2, then it will be question0,question1,question2 .. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your aproach is pretty bad. It's not a good idea to put everything in a long string and place it somewhere in your JS. But, this is not your question.

Just create a new variable in your script for counting.

```
var count = 0;
```

And then increase the count in your `createNew` function and place the value everywhere you need it in your element string.

```
++count;
'<input name="questions' + count + '" id="questions' + count + '"'
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to `count` the number of clicks 
and use that count in your script to have unique name attributes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var clicks = 0;
        function createNew() {
            clicks += 1;
            var ques = "questions" + clicks;
             $('#questionshowp1').append('<div class="form-group"><input name='+ques+'  id="questions1" class="form-control firstsec" placeholder="Text, Image URL, or LaTeX" value="" type="text"><div class="secondsec"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success exp-add" style="line-height:12px;" onclick="createNew(this);"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger exp-minus" style="line-height:12px;" onclick="deleteNew(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div></div>');
     $(evt).css('display', 'none');
     $(evt).siblings("button.btn-danger").css('display', 'block');
        };
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable **idCount** in your script and in `createNew` function increment its value.

```js
var idCount = 0;
function createNew(evt){
  idCount++;
     $('#questionshowp1').append('<div class="form-group"><input name="questions'+idCount+'" id="questions1" class="form-control firstsec" placeholder="Text, Image URL, or LaTeX" value="" type="text"><div class="secondsec"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success exp-add" style="line-height:12px;" onclick="createNew(this);">+<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger exp-minus" style="line-height:12px;" onclick="deleteNew(this)">-<i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div></div>');
     $(evt).css('display', 'none');
     $(evt).siblings("button.btn-danger").css('display', 'block');
}
function deleteNew(evnt){
     $(evnt).closest(".form-group").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questionshowp" id="questionshowp1">
<div class="form-group">
<input name="questions0" id="questions0" class="form-control firstsec" placeholder="Text, Image URL, or LaTeX" value="" type="text">
<div class="secondsec">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success exp-add" style="line-height:12px;" onclick="createNew(this);">+<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger exp-minus" style="line-height:12px;display:none;" onclick="deleteNew(this)">-<i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>                                                            
 </div>
 </div>
```