# How can i make a form with dynamic array and with removable inputs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ajax, associative-array

I want to make a form with html css js that support this feature

**Problem:**

Imagine i have an array like this:
[0=> [armature => 10,format => 2, concrete => 31],1=> [armature => 31,format => 21, concrete => 13],2=> [armature => 11,format => 21, concrete => 21]]

in my html inputs i have to name they in this way =>

```
<input name="column[0][armature]">
<input name="column[0][format]">
<input name="column[0][concrete]">
```

So this is easy to make inputs for it.. but the problem is send it as an array with ajax... because the html dont care about the `[` and treat them like a string...

So how can i get them as array... can you show me an example?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add name attribute of input field dynamically using Javascript/Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968875/how-to-add-name-attribute-of-input-field-dynamically-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @CreativeLearner No i dont think so... my problem is with arrays...